# Updating large dataframe with around 6500 rows into xlsm file using Xlwings in python

Tags: python, dataframe, xlwings, pywin

I am trying to update excel file with extension .xlsm with `ws[cellid].options(header=False, index=False).value = df`.It doesn't contains empty columns or Nan values or any equations.But the same code is working when I try to update few rows.When I try to execute I am getting this error

```
  self._oleobj_.Invoke(*(args + (value,) + defArgs))
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147024882), None)
```

I have tried with different versions of Xlwings and also some addin installations.Only problem with large data frames

Answer (score 0):

For big DataFrames, you can chunk the data like this:

```py
ws[cellid].options(header=False, index=False, chunksize=10_000).value = df
```

Check out the documentation for [options](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.Range.options).

Comment: I am getting the same error